# Javascript functions in the rails 4 asset pipeline tree

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to utilize a javascript function via the Chrome Console when I put that javascript function within the Rails Asset Pipeline Manifest. Here are the steps I've take to create and setup a simple Rails 4.2.4 App

```
$ rails new JavascriptExample
$ cd JavascriptExample
$ rails g scaffold Bear name:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

I then edit the `app/assets/javascripts/bears.coffee` and add a console log and a function.

```
console.log("asset pipeline sucks")
square = (x) -> x * x
```

Then I fire up the server

```
$ rails s
```

I visit `localhost:3000/bears` and in the Chrome Console I see that my first line of code has worked. However when I attempt the command `square(5);` in console I receive an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: square is not defined(…)`

Why can I not do it this way when this function is clearly loaded into `application.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your coffeescript was compiled to javascript

```
(function() {
  var square;

  console.log("asset pipeline sucks");

  square = function(x) {
    return x * x;
  };
}).call(this);
```

From [this](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/07_the_bad_parts.html): `the var keyword is reserved in CoffeeScript, and will trigger a syntax error if used. Local variables are created implicitly by default`, so it is not available in global scope as your expectation

To make it work, we can do something like this instead:

```
console.log("asset pipeline sucks")
@square = (x) -> x * x
```

Note that we have `@`
And now the compiled javascript will be:

```
(function() {
  console.log("asset pipeline sucks");

  this.square = function(x) {
    return x * x;
  };

}).call(this);
```